# Design - how to make clean code with deep hierarchy classes

Tags: class, communication, hierarchy

I have the following class structure:

[image]

And I don't know "where" to put Algorithm class. My nasty proposals are:

- If I set it in Class1 so it is a member variable, I have to pass Algorithm reference along Class2 (so I have set1 available), Class5 and Class6 (to have set2 available). I see it a nasty solution, because this algorithm could not be unique and more algorithms could be necessary with different ClassX dependencies, so this chain mechanism is not the best, AFAIK.
- Make the Algorithm a Singleton and destroy it when Class1 instance goes out of scope. This is cleaner from the point of view of dependency-awareness, but using a Singleton for this purpose looks to me to be a very code smell. What if more Algorithms get it onto scene?

Sure that another mechanism is possible without constant delegation of the Algorithm reference, but I don't know how. 
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itWaG.png)

Comment: What do you try to achieve? To propose a solution one must have what the problem is? Only the draft solution won't work. :)

Comment: My problem is the best design of the code (how), not the algorithmics behind (what). Class3 and Class6 somehow have to store some data into the class I call "Algorithm". Then, after set2 is called, Algorithm has to perform some transformation on the data that was set1'd. This is currently achieved, but I'm sure this is not the best way it can be done. Observer pattern could fit here?

Comment: What I am really asking is what is the user-story? Ex: I am going to implement a weather api in which when user gives a time and a place, then it gives a weather report.

Comment: I did know what you meant :). But the question is not about implementation, it's about design, which is user-story aware. Your weather app example may fit here, though.